# Regex pattern to match any character except the last one

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am trying to match a string using two different patterns to work together.
My source string is something like this:

`Text, white-spaces, new lines and more text then ^^^^<customtag>`

I need to get a group (the second one) that would capture one caret or none then a formatted HTML-like tag. So the first group would capture anything else.
It means that the string above should output this:

`(Group 1)`**`Text, white-spaces, new lines and more text then ^^^`**

`(Group 2)`**`^<customtag>`**

In the source string carets may be one, none or up to two thousands.
I need a good pattern that matches **all** those carets **except the last one**.
The code below is what I tried.

```
preg_match_all('/([\s\S]*\^*)(\^?<\w+>)$/', $string, $matches);
```

*Please note:* I used `[\s\S]` instead of the *dot* to match any character as well as white-spaces and new lines too.

Comment: Have you tried removing the ? in the second capture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may follow the below regex:

```
(?s)(.*)((\^|(?<!\^))<[^>]+>)
```

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/pA0yF7)

PHP code:

```
preg_match_all('/(?s)(.*)((\^|(?<!\^))<[^>]+>)/', $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as this:

```
preg_match_all('/(.*)((\^<[^>]*>)|([^\^]<[^>]*>))$/', $string, $matches);
```

See it working here: http://regexr.com?383g9

In this other link it is working fine: http://regex101.com/r/eQ3vV7

Comment: I think he mentioned no . dot . :)

Comment: @l'L'l: OP mentioned that because is unaware of a `s` flag

Comment: @Jorge Campos: I don't see it working on that link actually :-S

Comment: Thast because the site change my expression if you copy the expression the it is here without the initial/  and end/ it will work... If you see the difference the site put two &lt; instead of <

Comment: Edited with new site.